# How to edit javascript runtime in browser?

Tags: javascript

I want to edit javascript for my web page on fly while loading. How should I achieve that?
Suppose I have a web page and I want to edit a particular script file in firebug or I want to edit particular function value, how to achieve that using dev tools?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQZio5DlSXM by @paulirish

Comment: have you tried fiddler ?

Comment: ?? how would fiddler edit the script being loaded?

Comment: I think the comment by codepo8 in Tushar video link is the most usefull. use the console to overwrite the function